# Add Commas To My String

Tags: javascript

I need help adding a comma to `MileagePointsObj.innerHTML` in `calcMileagePoints` function.  Right now it's set to round to the nearest 10.

```
<script type="text/javascript">     
        window.onload=function() {
            LapTimeObj = document.getElementById('InputLaptime');
            RaceLengthObj = document.getElementById('InputRaceLength');
            MileagePointsObj = document.getElementById('TDMileagePoints');
            document.getElementById('btnReset').onclick = resetInputs;
            document.getElementById('btnCalc').onclick = calcMileagePoints;
        }
        function resetInputs() {
            LapTimeObj.value = '';
            RaceLengthObj.value = '';
            MileagePointsObj.innerHTML = '';
        }
        function calcMileagePoints() {
            var LapTime = new Number(LapTimeObj.value);
            var RaceLength = new Number(RaceLengthObj.value);
            MileagePointsObj.innerHTML = '';

            MileagePointsObj.innerHTML = parseInt(((RaceLength*60*60)/LapTime)*10 / 10, 10) * 10;
        }
    </script>
```

Thanks in advance!

Jerome

Comment: Use `number.toLocaleString()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString

Comment: what do you mean by "add a comma" ? You want a decimal number or just add a comma after the number ?

Comment: regex to add commas to a large number in the first answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901102/how-to-print-a-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-javascript

Comment: @JohnEllmore Ellmore, how would I implement that?  I'm rather new to making these kinds of changes.

Comment: The answer by @kemotoe implements this correctly

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the comments use [`toLocaleString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString)

Simple example

```js
let number = 123456789;
let numberWithComma = number.toLocaleString();
console.log(numberWithComma);
```

Comment: I got it put together.  Thanks guys!

MileagePointsObj.innerHTML = (parseInt(((RaceLength*60*60)/LapTime)*10 / 10, 10) * 10).toLocaleString()

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the help guys!

MileagePointsObj.innerHTML = (parseInt(((RaceLength*60*60)/LapTime)*10 / 10, 10) * 10).toLocaleString()